# How can I zoom multiple lines with multiple series in D3.js Chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I have chart with 3 y-axis and one x-axis. I must zoom all 3 axis. But D3.zoom() work only with one y-axis.

1) Is it possible to add another 2 axis?
2) Is it possible to set all 3 y-axis with center on 0? And if I zoom chart ticks must stay on same place?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each y-axis I create another zoom object

```
var zoom2 = d3.behavior.zoom()
                .y(yAxis2);
```

and then I update it in zoom callback

```
zoom.on('zoom', function(){
    zoom2.scale(zoom.scale());
    zoom2.translate(zoom.translate());
    // update stuff
});
```

Comment: could you please make new question for it ? That would be helpful for more people